# How do I listen to events for elements in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to use Polymer's UI elements (e.g., iron-icons, paper-button, etc.) without making custom elements or templates.

For example, let's say I have:

```
<paper-button id="my-button">Click me</paper-button>
```

How do I listen for the 'click' event? Simply adding an event listener to 'click' for the ID 'my-button' doesn't work.

Comment: What have code have you written so far? Have you checked the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html)?

Comment: I tried `$('my-button').addEventListener('click', myFunc)` but that doesn't work; it seems like polymer is swallowing the click event somehow?

The docs say how to do it if you are declaring a [new `<dom-module>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html), but I'm not making a new module... I want to re-use `<paper-button>`, ideally without wrapping it in a new module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should just work? I'm assuming you want to use Polymer UI elements in the main doc (index.html) without having to create any custom components. Say you have

```
<paper-button id="btn">Click me</paper-button>
```

in index.html. Via vanilla js,

```
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {...});
```

and via jQuery,

```
$("#btn").on("click", function (e, u) {...});
```

p/s: I'd write a quick jsbin as a demo, but rawgit seems to be having issues, and I'm not aware of alternative CDNs that host Polymer Elements.

**Let me be clear: Polymer elements, and by extension web components, are designed to be framework-agnostic and, if properly coded, will work on their own - just like any other HTML element.** Please do not dom-bind for the sake of dom-binding. You **only** do so if you a) require Polymer's sugaring (like data-binding) in your use-case; and b) you want to use Polymer's sugaring from your `index.html` - if you don't, please don't add additional complexity to your app.

I've found a cdn serving polymer elements, so:

[Look, no dom-bind and elements are working with vanilla js.](http://jsbin.com/pijodevoba/edit?html,output)

[Look, no dom-bind and elements are working with jQuery.](http://jsbin.com/senifaxiqe/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: You'll probably also want to wrap your code in index.html in a `<template is="dom-bind"></template>` tag. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind) for details.

Comment: No, it's optional. Wrap with `dom-bind` only if you want to use Polymer's sugar (eg data-binding, observers, listeners, on-* events etc). Web components are generally designed to work on their own - like any other HTML element.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```html
<template is="dom-bind" id="t">
<paper-button id="my-button" on-click="buttonClicked">Click me</paper-button>
</template>

<script>
var template = document.querySelector('#t');
template.buttonClicked= function () {
    alert("he clicked me :)");

   };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "#my-button", "click", function() {
   alert();
});
```